# Does the 2-piece Marauder's bonus also affect the Companion active ability?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-demon-hunter

The 2-piece Marauder's set bonus causes Companion to summon *all* companions, instead of just the chosen one. Does activating Companion trigger the ability of all companions, or just the one you have chosen?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It triggers the abilities of all the companions.  As long as you have the set bonus it doesn't really matter what rune you use for companions you'll have all of them and all their activation abilities.

Comment: Wow! That's a really powerful set bonus!

Comment: @SaintWacko marauders set is one of the most powerful sets in the game right now, making DH the most played class

Comment: DH and Monk...every single game...